# If statements and && or ||

Tags: c#, if-statement, logical-operators

OK so I'm a beginner with C# and I am having trouble understanding the if statement below.

For this example INumber is declared as 8, dPrice is 0 and dTAX is 10.

```
        if (iNumber != 8 || iNumber != 9)
        {
            dPrice = dPrice + dTAX;
        }
```

Can somebody explain why it is entering the statement and adding the 10 from dTAX to dPrice?

I know changing it to && works, but why?

As I understand it, it should only enter the If statement, if iNumber does not equal 8 or 9, which here it does, so it should not enter.

Here are my outputs after running it through the || if statement.

```
        Inumber is: 8

        dPrice was: 0
        dPrice is now: 10

        dTAX is: 10
```

Can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: it's because your number is 8, then, your program will read `inumber !=8` will be return as `false` and `inumber !=9` will be return as `true`. but then you are working with `||` so, either one of them is `true` `dprice` is updated as well

Comment: It enters the if simply because it is a true statement that `8 != 8 or 8 != 9`

Comment: if (false OR true) == true, so it enters the block.

Comment: By the way, when debugging you can set a breakpoint inside the `if` and then hover your mouse over the `||` part, which will show you why it is entering the block, and the result of the *entire* if statement.

Comment: Thanks for the debug tip, didn't know hovering over showed data.

Comment: I have two standard American coins in my pocket. They add to thirty cents. One of them is not a quarter. What are the coins? Now that you know the answer to your question, you should be able to answer the puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is entering the statement because the statement becomes true when it calculates iNumber != 9

An || (Or Operator) in an if will be true if any statement is true.

Think of it this way..

```
8 != 8 is False
8 != 9 is True

if ( False || True )
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers everybody, my problem was I could not see how !=8 && != 9 could ever be true, I was not thinking with logic in mind, as I was only using the 1 Variable, but thanks anyway I understand now.

Answer (score 4):

The `if` conditional expression in this code will **always** evaluate as `true`:

```
if (iNumber != 8 || iNumber != 9)
```

When `iNumber` is `8`, it's not equal to `9`, so the 2nd part is `true`. When `iNumber` is `9`, it's not equal to `8`, so the first part is `true`. Anything else, and both sides are `true`.  `||` conditions result in `true` with either side is `true`. There's no way for this to ever be `false`. You want `&&` here instead of `||`:

```
if (iNumber != 8 && iNumber != 9)
```

Or you could use [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and get this:

```
if (! (iNumber == 8 || iNumber == 9))
```

Answer (score 2):

Logical AND (&&)

> The logical AND operator (&&) returns the boolean value true if both operands are true and returns false otherwise. The operands are implicitly converted to type bool prior to evaluation, and the result is of type bool. Logical AND has left-to-right associativity.

Logical OR (||)

> The logical OR operator (||) returns the boolean value true if either or both operands is true and returns false otherwise. The operands are implicitly converted to type bool prior to evaluation, and the result is of type bool. Logical OR has left-to-right associativity.

So if you have:

```
bool someVariable = true;
bool someOtherVariable = false;

if ((someVariable == true) && (someOtherVaribale == true))
{
    //This code will be executed
}

if ((someVaribale == true) || (someOtherVariable == true))
{
    //This code will be executed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should only enter the If statement, if iNumber does not equal 8 OR if iNumber does not equal 9.  It does not equal 9, so it will enter

Answer (score 1):

The statement is logically equivalent to

```
    if (!(iNumber == 8 && iNumber == 9))
    {
        dPrice = dPrice + dTAX;
    }
```

which is ALWAYS true since a number cannot be both 8 and 9.

You want:

```
    if (iNumber != 8 && iNumber != 9)
    {
        dPrice = dPrice + dTAX;
    }
```

or

```
    if (!(iNumber == 8 || iNumber == 9))
    {
        dPrice = dPrice + dTAX;
    }
```

whichever makes more sense to you, logically.

Answer (score 1):

The following is from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx):

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool
>   operands. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand
>   isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second
>   operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to
>   true or false.

In your example the first condition (!=8) is false because iNumber = 8, but the second condition is (!=9), which is true. So that's why it goes into the braces.

If instead you say !=8 && !=9, it will not go in the braces because it doesn't satisfy both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `||` ([Logical OR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f355wky8.aspx)), which would evaluate to true if any of the operand is true. So your first condition (`iNumber != 8`) is false but the second condition (`iNumber != 9`) is true, hence the overall result is true.

The reason it works with `&&` is that AND operator requires both operand to be true, to evaluate to true. If one of the operand is false the overall result is false.

You should see: [Truth Tables, Logic, and DeMorgan's Laws](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/truth_tables_and_logic.html)

Answer (score 0):

The || OR operator means only one OR the other has to be true. In this case, iNumber != 9, so that portion of the code is true and it enters the statement. I think you'll want to use the && AND operator to indicate that it can't be 8 AND it can't be 9.

Answer (score 0):

In English, this reads as: If iNumber is not 8 OR iNumber is not 9. 
iNumber is 8, which IS NOT 9 (your second check), so it drops into the if block.

You're describing an AND condition where it doesn't equal 8 and it doesn't equal 9.

Answer (score 0):

> it should only enter the If statement, if iNumber does not equal 8 or
>   9

That would be:

```
if (!(iNumber == 8 || iNumber == 9))
...
```

Comment: How does this even answer the question of why? `Can somebody explain why it is entering the statement and adding the 10 from dTAX to dPrice?`

Comment: It is what the OP meant. He wrote his line not noticing that this is what he meant. The OP does understand the concepts of OR and AND. He just has a simple logic-typo.

Comment: This does fix the problem though

Comment: It fixes the problem.. Which is not answering the question.. If you asked your professor why, and they just give you this, would you feel as though your question has been answered?

Comment: If you knew math but asked your professor why 10 divided by 2 isn't 1/2 and he would start explaining division to you - how would you feel? That's what the other answers are doing. You would want your professor to simply tell you "Um, did you notice which you are dividing by witch?". That would be the helpful answer.

Comment: My answer kinda does both I think, it solves the problem and explains why it exists in the first place.

Comment: Okay, let me re-iterate... The OP noted that `I know changing it to && works, but why?`. That comment is the exact same as the if statement you provided... Your answer has the exact same content as the question, but with no explanation

Comment: @Rariolu I have no problem with your answer. I was responding to `austin wernli` who thinks there is something wrong with my answer.

Comment: @User42 Fair enough, people on this site are so picky

Comment: @austinwernli Exactly. And that is what the OP didn't notice.

Comment: @Rariolu Hear Hear! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (iNumber != 8 && iNumber != 9)
```

This means "if iNumber is not equal to eight and iNumber is not equal to nine". Your statement:

```
if (!Number != 8 || iNumber != 9)
```

Means "if !iNumber is not equal to eight or iNumber is not equal to nine" which is true as long as iNumber is not equal to one of those values, and because it can only hold one value and not two simultaneously, this statement will always be true.

Answer (score -1):

Maintaining the menu of a large web site is difficult and time consuming.

In ASP.NET the menu can be stored in a file to make it easier to maintain. This file is normally called web.sitemap, and is stored in the root directory of the web.

In addition, ASP.NET has three new navigation controls:

Dynamic menus
TreeViews
Site Map Path